# websocket : python server and client js -> didn't work

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, autobahn

I am trying to use **websocket** over the web, with a **python server** and a **javascript client**. For **python**, I am using an `Autobahn (http://autobahn.ws/python/)` to create a **websoket server**. When I use a python client (still with autobahn), all work fine. But when I try to use a webpage client, nothing works.

Python (server) code :

```
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, \
                                       WebSocketServerFactory

import asyncio
import json

def fastsquare(x):
   return x * x


def slowsquare(x):
   asyncio.sleep(2)
   return x * x

class SlowSquareServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
   @asyncio.coroutine
   def onOpen(self):
      print("WebSocket connection open.")

   @asyncio.coroutine
   def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
      if not isBinary:
         obj_tmp = json.loads(payload.decode('utf8'))
         obj = json.loads(obj_tmp)
         print (obj)
         try:
            if obj[2] == "little" :
               res = slowsquare(obj[3]["valeur"])
            else :
               res = fastsquare(obj[3]["valeur"])
         except Exception as e:
            self.sendClose(1000, str(e))
         else:
            obj = json.dumps(res).encode('utf8')
            print (str(obj))
            self.sendMessage(json.dumps(res).encode('utf8'))



if __name__ == '__main__':

   import asyncio

   factory = WebSocketServerFactory("ws://localhost:9000", debug = False)
   factory.protocol = SlowSquareServerProtocol

   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   coro = loop.create_server(factory, 'localhost', 9000)
   server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

   try:
      loop.run_forever()
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
      pass
   finally:
      server.close()
      loop.close()
```

And this is my javascript code :

```
<script>
function carre(){
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.0.15:9000");

    ws.onopen = function(){
        console.log("Connection is open..."); 
        // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
        val = document.getElementById("val").value;
        var_json = '[2, "2262626262", "big", {"valeur" : ' + val + '}]';
        ws.send(var_json);
        console.log("json envoyé : " + var_json);
    };

    ws.onmessage = function (evt){ 
        var received_msg = evt.data;
        document.getElementById('carre').value = received_msg;
        console.log("JSon reçu : " + received_msg);
    };

    ws.onclose = function(){ 
        // websocket is closed.
        console.log("Connection is closed..."); 
    };
}
</script>


<p><input type="text" id="val" value="6"/><input type="button" OnClick="carre();" value="mettre au carre !"/></p>
<p>resultat du carre : <input type="text" id="carre" /></p>
```

Comment: Please provide console messages from browser of what it says. As it is not enough information of your debugging efforts in order to help you out.
In first glance, looks like you binding socket to `localhost` but really should use just port without specifying any hostname on server side.

Comment: Hi, i d'ont have any error, i just have "connection is closed..." from my ws.onclose.

Comment: onclose event provides object with details as first argument in callback, what that object contains?

Comment: You may try looking at my demo in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgpPm9N338s with source reference @ github

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
obj_tmp = json.loads(payload.decode('utf8'))
obj = json.loads(obj_tmp)
```

with

```
obj = json.loads(payload)
```

Comment: hello, I made this because the first json.loads give me a string and i can't recover data (ex : obj[3]["valeur"]). With a second json.load my string become a json.

Comment: This answer does not fixes a problem, but just points to unrelated to issue area in code.

Comment: If this actually fixes the problem, then my appologies, and will remove - once 2 hours past (SO limitations..)

Comment: Yes, honestly, I tested it. Works for me. Probably the OP could test it with the change applied and see if it works for him/her.

Comment: Hello, i tried to modify but it still doesn't work :/.

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/oberstet/9526275 and https://gist.github.com/oberstet/9526288